# MATLAB Compiler Licensing

Tags: matlab

I am planning to deploy a MATLAB application using the MATLAB compiler.
My plan is to compile the code using the toolbox, install the runtime in a web server, and create a website that calls this application and retrieve some results.

My question is regarding the licenses required:
I already know that MCR is royalty free for desktop applications. What about web aplications?

I do NOT need to buy "[MATLAB Production Server](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-production-server/?s_tid=brdcrb)", right?

obs: I already have MATLAB Compiler license

Comment: Looking at the description of the licensing tag, i'm rather convinced that this is not how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: Indeed... I removed it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal concerns, not programming.

Comment: Should I move it to SuperUser?

Comment: The best place for it is probably on MathWorks' own forums, where you have a decent chance of a direct answer from an employee.  Anyone else is just offering armchair lawyer advice, and I think we know how reliable that isn't.

Comment: Ok,  I will delete the post soon

Comment: @BenVoigt As an ex-MathWorker, I can offer more than armchair advice, and an answer that is almost certainly more direct than would typically be provided by a current MathWorker on MATLAB Answers, who would most likely suggest that you contact your sales account manager for a discussion.

Comment: that's true... I hate the "contact your sales account manager"... I has happened several times

Comment: Also, read your license agreement. There are probably a lot of restrictions and definitions in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regard to licensing, that's correct. The MCR can be redistributed and used royalty-free, and you don't need to buy MATLAB Production Server.

Technically, however, this is unlikely to be a good solution unless your web application is very small scale, and is OK to be very slow. Each time your web application needs to make a call to the MATLAB component, it will need to start up the MCR, which can take rather a long time. In addition, if you need to support multiple people using the web application simultaneously, multiple copies of the MCR will start up at once, and you may run out of memory fast.

You may like to consider using either one of the MATLAB Builder products, which enable you to integrate better with web applications, or MATLAB Production Server, which will enable you to scale better.

Comment: Great answer....  Since it is really a small prototype,  I estimate that the maximum number of simultaneous user would be 10...  I think I should be fine...   However,  I still have one question: Since Matlab builder NE and JA use MCR,  I would have the same performance issues,  correct?

Comment: Well, the only real answer is to try it, but I would be pessimistic about starting up ten MCRs simultaneously. MATLAB Builder NE and JA do both also use the MCR, but there are interesting things you can do with them. For example, you can write a small Java (or .NET) app that just starts up an MCR and then sits there, waiting for an instruction over some socket from the web app. In that way the MCR only has to be started once, not each time the web app is called. As far as I know that's not possible with MATLAB Compiler. cont...

Comment: ...In fact, if you run a bunch of those miniature MCR apps at once, just sitting there waiting for instructions, and then you write a bit of a framework to manage, sequence and parcel out requests from the web app to all those miniature MCR apps, then you have basically implemented MATLAB Production Server.

Comment: ok, i will take it into consideration